# Change name of output file and location Source Generator Visual Studio Extnesion

Tags: c#, .net, xml, code-generation, visual-studio-extensions

I am using the VsixCommunity/Community.VisualStudio.Toolkit to create a Visual Studio exntension which takes in a .XML file and returns another .XML file but with different contents.

I have the command in place and the SourceGenerator, extending BaseCodeGeneratorWithSite.

But I want to change the name of the output file name and the location (to have it in some folder present in the project).

Presently it takes the name of the input file and adds {1^n} at the end since the exentension are same. so test.xml will output test1.xml. I want to hardcode the name to be updated_test.xml for example.

I want to do this because I am facing some issue with the output file being of the same extension:

https://github.com/VsixCommunity/Community.VisualStudio.Toolkit/issues/436

TLDR:
I have a VSIX extension which runs on a .xml file of a particular format and creates another .xml (expecting only one file) in some different format using the provided file content.

Now when I run this extension on a .xml file, it goes in a loop when creating the generated .xml file with the filename in the format of {fileName}1^n.xml

Suppose I run the extension on a test.xml, it sets the custom tool and creates test1.xml, test11.xml, test111.xml and so on, until I terminate the program.

When I change the GetDefaultExtension to ".cs" this doesn't happen and then it only creates one file.